# fgets() Warning: Not a valid stream resource

Tags: php, command-line, user-input

I had a script that was working fine until suddenly my input reads failed for:

> Warning: Not a valid stream resource in
>   /data/users/myusername/processingscript.php on line 1036

and fails at line with `fgets()`. My function is below

```
function read_stdin($question)
{
    echo "\033[1;37m".$question;
    $fr=fopen("php://stdin","r"); // open our file pointer to read from stdin
    $input = fgets($fr,128); // read a maximum of 128 characteyrs
    $input = strtolower(rtrim($input)); // trim any trailing spaces.
    fclose ($fr); // close the file handle
    return $input; // return the text entered
}
```

I have no idea what has happened and can't find an answer elsewhere.

Comment: Can you supply ALL the error message please

Comment: Added the full error message